# UIImages or UIViews are not colliding each other in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I am trying to collide two UIViews each other for using pan gesture. Now i can able to drag one view but when dragging view to next view its collide each other. It goes behind other view.

Here is the screenshot result:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code I used to drag, pan and collide of physics property.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var greenSquare: UIView?
var redSquare: UIView?
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator?
var snap: UISnapBehavior!
var panGesture       = UIPanGestureRecognizer()


@IBAction func pan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapPoint: CGPoint = sender.location(in: view)

    if (snap != nil) {
        animator?.removeBehavior(snap)
    }

    snap = UISnapBehavior(item: greenSquare!, snapTo: tapPoint)
    animator?.addBehavior(snap)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var dimen = CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 120, height: 120)
    greenSquare = UIView(frame: dimen)
    greenSquare?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    dimen = CGRect(x: 130, y: 25, width: 100, height: 100)
    redSquare = UIView(frame: dimen)
    redSquare?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    self.view.addSubview(greenSquare!)
    self.view.addSubview(redSquare!)

    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)

    let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [greenSquare!, redSquare!])
    let direction = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 1.0)
    gravity.gravityDirection = direction

    let boundries = UICollisionBehavior(items: [greenSquare!, redSquare!])
    boundries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

    let bounce = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [greenSquare!, redSquare!])
    bounce.elasticity = 0.5



    animator?.addBehavior(bounce)
    animator?.addBehavior(boundries)
    animator?.addBehavior(gravity)


    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(draggedView(sender:)))
    greenSquare?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    greenSquare?.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

 }

@objc func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    greenSquare?.center = CGPoint(x: (greenSquare?.center.x)! + translation.x, y: (greenSquare?.center.y)! + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}



}//class`
```

Anyone can help me out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the animator only recognizes the collision at the origin of the greenSquare. In this case it is at the top of the screen. You can update the collision location on the animator after you move the greenSquare. Add `animator?.updateItem(usingCurrentState: greenSquare!)`
to the end of the `draggedView` method. You do not need to use `UISnapBehavior` for this so you can remove the `IBAction func pan` method at the top of your code. The `updateItem(usingCurrentState:)` call will reset where the collision barrier is when you are moving the view manually and it is not being done by the physics engine.